# change anchor tag inner html by title using javascript

Tags: javascript, title, innerhtml

i have an anchor tag as follows:

```
<a title=“mytagname”>My name is akira</a>
```

I want to write a javascript so that I can search the a tag with the title value and change the inner html of that.

Comment: If you're going to only change the *text* inside the element, then don't use innerHTML. There's a very nice `textContent` DOM interface for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
function changeContentByTagName(tagName, newContent) {
  var elem = document.querySelector('a[title='+ tagName +']');
  if (elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = newContent;
  }
}
```

usage: `changeContentByTagName('mytagname', 'My name is Tetsuo');`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using jQuery

```
function serchAndChange (title, content){
    var selector = '[title='+title+']';
    var $element = $(selector);
    if($element){
        $element.html(content);
    }
}
```